# Unable to install 'gdtools' package (I am using Red Hat 5.11)

Tags: r

I ran

`install.packages('gdtools','/usr/lib64/R/library',repos='http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/')`

> Error:
>
> raster_to_base64.cpp:159: error: ‘cairo_format_stride_for_width’ was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [raster_to_base64.o] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gdtools’
>   * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/gdtools’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/RtmpmMpmpJ/downloaded_packages’
>   Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
>   Making 'packages.html' ... done
>
> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("gdtools", "/usr/lib64/R/library", repos = "http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/") :
>     installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status

---

Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

try install cairo and use cmd install.packages('gdtools',configure.vars='INCLUDE_DIR=path to cairo LIB_DIR= path to cairo'